# SUM columns on the same sheet based on conditions or SUMIFS from another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is a small sample table

```
+--------+-------+--------+
| COL 1  | COL 2 | COL 3  |
+--------+-------+--------+
| abc123 | Total |        |
+--------+-------+--------+
| abc123 | cat1  | 100.00 |
+--------+-------+--------+
| abc123 | cat2  | 200.00 |
+--------+-------+--------+
| def123 | Total |        |
+--------+-------+--------+
| def123 | cat1  | 100.00 |
+--------+-------+--------+
| def123 | cat2  | 200.00 |
+--------+-------+--------+
```

In COL 3, IF COL 2 is "Total" I need to SUM everything in COL 3 for each row in COL1 that is the same. (EG. COL3 Total row should be 300.00 for abc123 and then 300.00 for def123)  Otherwise if COL 2 is NOT "Total" I need to do `SUMIFS('Sheet3'!N:N,'Sheet3'!A:A,Sheet2!A473,'Sheet3'!Q:Q,Sheet2!Q473)*Sheet4!$U$2)`

How can I can I accomplish the first part of the SUM?

Edit:

I think my example is too rigid and appears like it is set.

Let me see if I can explain in more fluid terms.  I will have to describe this some what in database terms.  All of the columns are on one sheet for the purposes of the "Total" portion.

COL 1 is my partition.  Each of the "ID's" in COL 1 consists of 57 rows.  Within 1 of those 57 rows is "Total" in another column, in the example that is COL 2.

So I have a large table that in COL 1 there are say 5 different ID's with 57 rows for each ID resulting in 285 rows.

Now I had a sorting function that would likely make this whole thing easier, but that function is crashing excel and not sorting both required sorts ( https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/sort-function-causes-a-crash-and-does-not-perform-secondary-sort/m-p/1477123#M66205 )

I suppose if I can get the sorting function to stop crashing excel this becomes slightly easier as then "Total" is consistently placed in row 2, 58, 116, etc. and I can add up everything below it.  Right now, because that sort doesn't work, I have to add up everything from COL 3 that is NOT assigned to "Total" in COL 2 and has the same ID in COL1.

So in the table above abc123 is 3 rows and I need to add up the two rows that are not total for abc123 and have the formula spit out 300 into COL 3 for total.

Then def123 needs the same treatment.

Here is the tough part: the sorting is inconsistent because the data comes from a Redshift query so it is random for each ID.  The IDs themselves are in random order.  I think I can get the sort for COL 1 to work without crashing excel, but the secondary sort with the custom order is crashing it.

Comment: Should that read *'if COL 2 is NOT "Total"'*, instead of *'if COL 3 is NOT "Total"'*?

Comment: I am *presuming* that you have already tried using a straight `SUMIFS`, and run into the issue with Circular References?  If so, that (i.e. *"what have you already tried"*) would have been good information to include in the question.

Comment: Would you mind rephrasing your problem statement or share the output table for better understanding ?

Comment: Also, is this code on `Sheet2`, `Sheet3`, `Sheet4` or on a fourth sheet (`Sheet1`?)  I'm not quite sure what the relative references should be in that final formula...

Comment: @Belle the output table would just have a formula in COL3 where COL2 = Total that SUMS COL3 for each COL1 "ID"  so COL3 row 2 would be 300.00 and COL3 row 5 would be 300.00.  If I really need to make a table for that I suppose I can. Typo fixed

Comment: https://ufile.io/6377g1jd example data in CSV.

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid the Circular Reference error when trying to Total a column is to use *two* Sums, one above and one below.

So, assuming that your Columns 1, 2 and 3 are A, B and C, and that data starts in Row 2 (Row 1 being a header), you need the Sum of cells *above* the current row:

```
SUMIFS(C$1:C1, A$1:A1, A2)
```

Plus the Sum of the cells *below* the current row:

```
SUMIFS(C3:INDEX(C:C, 1+COUNTA(A:A)), A3:INDEX(A:A, 1+COUNTA(A:A)), A2)
```

(Note that this will actually terminate one row *above* and *below* the dataset)

Put this together with an `IF` statement:

```
=IF(B2="Total", SUMIFS(C$1:C1, A$1:A1, A2) + SUMIFS(C3:INDEX(C:C, 1+COUNTA(A:A)), A3:INDEX(A:A, 1+COUNTA(A:A)), A2), EXISTING_FORMULA_HERE)
```

---

Alternatively, you could try writing an Array Formula to calculate the `SUM` directly, a bit like when using multiple conditions in a `MATCH`, something like this:  (not enough information in the question to do this exactly)

```
=SUMPRODUCT('Sheet3'!N:N*(COUNTIFS(A:A,'Sheet3'!$A:A)>0)*(COUNTIFS(B:B,'Sheet3'!$Q:Q)>0))
```

(Sum of `Sheet3!N:N` when a row exists in the current sheet that matches columns `Sheet3!A:A` in Column A and `Sheet3!Q:Q` in Column B)

Note that working on Entire Columns with Array Formulae is quite slow, so you may want to limit those just to the Used Range

Comment: I think my example is a little too rigid.  The Total isn't always in row 2.  Let me see if I can edit the question for more fluid clarity

Comment: @Shenanigator This formula will work for any row when you drag it down - the `IF` statement is to detect whether or not this is the Total row.  It's just easiest to *write* it for Row 2.

Comment: Okay let me give a more comprehensive table so you can see why I think this isn't going to work the way it needs to, at least with out sorting.  Give me a few to build a larger example table.

Comment: https://ufile.io/6377g1jd here is an example CSV.  Mostly real data, just edited to keep confidential data confidential with renaming.  I would post the whole table in the question, but it seems excessive